# Vector of a class resetting member variables after for loop

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I have an assignment where we need to use this basic structure of vectors and classes to learn about parent and child classes and polymorphism. Here is the code of the function I'm supposed to write:

```
void assignStudents(vector<Student*>& v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a study level: ";
        string input;
        cin >> input;
        if (input == "graduate")
        {
            Graduate inputClass;
            Student* inputParentClassPtr = &inputClass;
            v.push_back(inputParentClassPtr);
            v[i]->addToVector(input);
            inputParentClassPtr = nullptr;

        }
        else if (input == "undergraduate")
        {
            Undergraduate inputClass;
            Student* inputParentClassPtr = &inputClass;
            inputParentClassPtr->addToVector(input);
            v.push_back(inputParentClassPtr);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid response, either graduate or undergraduate" << endl;
            i--;
        }

    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<string> studyLevels = v[i]->getStudyLevels();
        size_t size = studyLevels.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cout << studyLevels[j];
        }
    }
}
```

I debug the program and every time the first `for` loop moves on to the next iteration, every member variable inside each object in my `vector` goes blank, but then when I add a new object into the `vector`, then call the `addToVector()` function they come back.

I added the bottom `for` loop to check if any editing is happening, and once I get to that bottom `for` loop, every member variable is empty again.

I have the `Student` class `vector` where I am adding `Undergraduate` and `Graduate` classes to. Every `Student` class has a protected `vector` inside called `levels`. I need to add the class to `vector` that holds all my objects, then edit the member variable `vector` to include the string representing the type of class it is.

Why do the member variables (`levels`) go blank every time it finishes an iteration of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just focus on one part, as the same issue appears twice in your code.

```
{
    Graduate inputClass; // create local student "on the stack"
    Student* inputParentClassPtr = &inputClass;
    v.push_back(inputParentClassPtr); // store address of student
    v[i]->addToVector(input);
    inputParentClassPtr = nullptr; // has no real effect
} // inputClass goes out of scope and is destroyed here
```

When the block ends, the local "stack" variables from that block are destroyed.  That means the `Graduate` object is no longer valid, and the pointer you stored in `v` is now pointing at something unusable.

To fix that, you need to create the objects in dynamic memory.

You should change your vector to store `std::unique_ptr<Student>`, and create the objects using `std::make_unique()`, like this:

```
auto inputParentClassPtr = std::make_unique<Graduate>();
v.push_back(std::move(inputParentClassPtr));
```

But, if you can't do that, you will need to use `new` instead, like this:

```
Student* inputParentClassPtr = new Graduate();
v.push_back(inputParentClassPtr);
```

Either way, even though `inputParentClassPtr` is still destroyed at the end of the block, it is only a pointer and the `Graduate` object it pointed to is still alive.

If you use `new`, you'll then need to `delete` all the objects in the vector when you are done using them, or you'll have a memory leak. Using `std::unique_ptr` will handle that for you.